# Find the time duration/length of an audio file uploaded to a React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, file-upload, mp3

I have a React web application (create-react-app) that takes song uploads using react-hook-forms and sends it to my Node/express server using axios.
I'd like to determine the length of the song and store this value in my postgresql database before sending the audio file to be stored in an AWS S3 bucket.

[Here is an example of an mp3 console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3fKA.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData). Once you've got an audio context object, you can use the `decodeAudioData` method to do what you're trying to do.  That method takes a callback function that takes one argument: an `AudioBuffer` that has a read-only `duration` property. That is,

```
audioContext.decodeAudioData(audioData, (buffer) => {
    const duration = buffer.duration;
    // do stuff with the duration
});
```